# How to add a prefix to all taxonomy terms of a given vocabulary?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 10

I wish that any `term` will have a prefix like `articles in the topic of` so to get:

**`Articles in the topic of term`**.

How to do that?

Comment: This should be applied on the page title, not the term itself.

Comment: SEOwise I am not sure I'd like it only to the page title but okay, how to do just that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default taxonomy term view [admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term], you can add the prefix either in title of the view with token or in the override title field as shown in the below screenshots.

[image]
OR
[image]